# NextJS 13 middleware rewrite does not working properly on POST method

Tags: javascript, typescript, http, next.js, middleware

I wrote NextJS middleware that rewrites request to other internal server

```js
import {NextRequest, NextResponse, URLPattern} from "next/server";
import {endpoint} from "@/utils";

export const config = {
    matcher: "/api/:path*"
}

const pattern = new URLPattern({pathname: "/api/:path*"})

export async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {

    const result = pattern.exec(req.url)

    console.log(result)
    if (result) {
        const path = result.pathname.groups.path

        return NextResponse.rewrite(`${endpoint}/${path}`)
    }
}
```

this code works for GET method but does not for POST method(internal server doesn't receive request body)

when I wrote rewrite in `next.config.js` it worked

```js
async rewrites() {
    return [
        {
            source: "/api/:path*",
            destination: `${process.env.API_ENDPOINT}/:path*`,
        },
    ]
},
```

How can I get it work using NextJS middleware?

I need to use NextJS middleware to append additional headers to request and that `next.config.js` method does not work either when I create middleware function(even if that function does nothing at all)

Comment: it seems that it doesn't work only in dev environment, it worked for me In production server